# Connected app that creates reports inside an client org account

Tags: api, salesforce1-app, app

I want to create a connected app that creates a report inside a client org account.

The main idea (till now) that I have is to create my client app, integrate it via OAuth with salesforce, and then, when a user logs in my client app, my client app via Metadata API creates the report inside the client's org account, and after that, it runs the report from my client app but populated (of course) with client org data.

with that in mind..

Is this a feasible? is it a reasonable way to do it? are there other ways to acommplish it?
Any suggestion is always welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the use case?